# Ensure that type parameter is correct

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generics

I have create a class named `Box` which have one type parameter. It is declared like this:

`public class Box<T> {...}`

I have also created a table that contain these boxes and it have getters for many different operations on this table (get selected etc). The declaration looks like this:

`public class BoxContainer<T> {...}`. If I write `new BoxContainer<Animal>()` the get selected methods return `Animal`. That is obvious. But is  is it possible to ensure that BoxContainer only accepts type parameters that are of type `Box<T>`? I tried to write `public class BoxContainer<Box<T>> {...}` but that isn't allowed for some reason. Is this possible? Or are the better ways?

Comment: I don't really get the relations between a `Box` and a `BoxContainer`, could you provide a full code snippet?

Comment: Does the type `T` for BoxContainer have to be same as the type `T` for `Box`?

Answer (score 1):

Use second typed param

```
public class BoxContainer<T, Y extends Box<T>> {...}
```

Or just use Box inside container:

```
public class BoxContainer<T> {
      List<Box<T>> innerList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`BoxContainer<T>` is the correct generic type. If you want to accept only `Box<T>` objects for your `BoxContainer` class, you can simply restrict the signatures of methods/constructors:

```
public class BoxContainer<T> {
  private final Box<T> box;

  public BoxContainer(Box<T> box) {
    this.box = box;
  }

  public Box<T> getBox() {
    return box;
  }

  public T getObjectFromBox() {
     return box.getObject(); // assumes getObject returns object of type T
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is a generic for type. It is only specifying that any type of an Object can be used but no primitives. Thats why it returns `Animal` when you use animal

Comment: Sorry, I think I was confused on this question when I wrote this. My apologies.